# PostgreSQL stable functions in query

Tags: postgresql, postgres-9.6

I'm have some data model which consists of couple tables and I need to filter them.

It is two functions `funcFast` and `funcList`. `funcFast` can return fast result is table need to be filtered by `funcList` or not. `funcList` return list of allowed ids. I marked functions as STABLE but they run not as fast as I expect:)

I create couple of example functions:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION funcFastPlPgSql(res boolean)
returns boolean as $$
    begin return res; end
$$ language plpgsql stable;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION funcList(cnt int)
returns setof integer as $$
    select generate_series(1, cnt)
$$ language sql stable;
```

And tests.

Case 1. Filter only by fast function work OK:

```sql
explain analyze
with obs as (select generate_series(1, 1000000) as id)
select count(*) from obs 
where funcFastPlPgSql(true)
```

Query plan is:

```sql
Aggregate  (cost=27.76..27.77 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=573.258..573.259 rows=1 loops=1)
  CTE obs
    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..5.01 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=0.006..114.327 rows=1000000 loops=1)
  ->  Result  (cost=0.25..20.25 rows=1000 width=0) (actual time=0.038..489.942 rows=1000000 loops=1)
        One-Time Filter: funcfastplpgsql(true)
        ->  CTE Scan on obs  (cost=0.25..20.25 rows=1000 width=0) (actual time=0.012..392.504 rows=1000000 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.184 ms
Execution time: 576.177 ms
```

Case 2. Filter only by slow function work OK too:

```sql
explain analyze
with obs as (select generate_series(1, 1000000) as id)
select count(*) from obs 
where  id in (select funcList(1000))
```

Query plan is:

```sql
Aggregate  (cost=62.26..62.27 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=469.344..469.344 rows=1 loops=1)
  CTE obs
    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..5.01 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=0.006..106.144 rows=1000000 loops=1)
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=22.25..56.00 rows=500 width=0) (actual time=1.566..469.202 rows=1000 loops=1)
        Hash Cond: (obs.id = (funclist(1000)))
        ->  CTE Scan on obs  (cost=0.00..20.00 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=0.009..359.580 rows=1000000 loops=1)
        ->  Hash  (cost=19.75..19.75 rows=200 width=4) (actual time=1.548..1.548 rows=1000 loops=1)
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 44kB
              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=17.75..19.75 rows=200 width=4) (actual time=1.101..1.312 rows=1000 loops=1)
                    Group Key: funclist(1000)
                    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..5.25 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=0.058..0.706 rows=1000 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.141 ms
Execution time: 472.183 ms
```

Case 3. But then two function combined I expect what the best case should be close to [case 1] and worst case should be close to [case 2], but:

```sql
explain analyze
with obs as (select generate_series(1, 1000000) as id)
select count(*) from obs
where funcFastPlPgSql(true) or id in (select funcList(1000))
```

Query plan is:

```sql
Aggregate  (cost=286.93..286.94 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1575.775..1575.775 rows=1 loops=1)
  CTE obs
    ->  Result  (cost=0.00..5.01 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=0.008..131.372 rows=1000000 loops=1)
  ->  CTE Scan on obs  (cost=7.75..280.25 rows=667 width=0) (actual time=0.035..1468.007 rows=1000000 loops=1)
        Filter: (funcfastplpgsql(true) OR (hashed SubPlan 2))
        SubPlan 2
          ->  Result  (cost=0.00..5.25 rows=1000 width=4) (never executed)
Planning time: 0.100 ms
Execution time: 1578.624 ms
```

What I am missing here? Why query with two together functions runs much longer and how to fix it?

Comment: I can't tell you the "why" of the slowness, but if you put the call to `funcFastPlPgSql` in case 3 in a subquery (i.e. `WHERE (SELECT funcFastPlPgSql(true)) OR...` you'll get your desired speed. Seems strange to me because PG should know it can only ever return a single value (based on it being STABLE and a hardcoded input of TRUE), so presumably should only call it once and use the result on every test. It does that for the subquery but doesn't appear to do that for a standard call.